# Window Manager cant create view

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view, android-windowmanager

WindowManager cannot create a view and the application crashes after launch. I'm trying to make an image on top of all windows, but the WindowManager can't add a view. Judging by the log, the application crashes after `windowManager.addView`

On MainActivity:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("SuperShot", "started");
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);

    floatingButton = findViewById(R.id.activate);

    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent permissionService = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(permissionService, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    Intent floatingButtonService = new Intent(this, FloatingButton.class);
    startService(floatingButtonService);
}
```

On FloatingButton service:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("SuperShot", "INTENT");

    ImageView floatingButton = MainActivity.floatingButton;

    Log.i("SuperShot", "button");

    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Log.i("SuperShot", "WINDOW MANAGING");
    final LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
    windowManager.addView(floatingButton, layoutParams);

    Log.i("SuperShot", "WINDOW MANAGED");

    try {
        OnTouchListener onTouchListener = getOnTouchListener(layoutParams);
        floatingButton.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        Log.i("SuperShot", "all good");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e("SuperShot", exception.getMessage());
    }
}

private LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
    Log.i("SuperShot", "layparams_start");
    final LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    layoutParams.x = 0;
    layoutParams.y = 100;
    Log.i("SuperShot", "layparams_end");
    return layoutParams;
}
```

On logs:[image: logs]

AND
[image]

Help me understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think that you forgot to add your crash log

Comment: I edited, check, pls

Comment: Your problem is not at the `windowManager.addView` but because you are trying to start a service from the background... see log at `android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not
allowed to
start service Intent { cmp=com.example.shots/.FloatingButton }: app is in background ...`